# Windows 10 bug at launch

Tags: windows, windows-10, boot

When I start Windows 10 the screen beginning to flash with a green background. After 2-3 minutes desktop appears and Windows 10 starts working. I've tried to reinstall Windows after formatting the SSD, but it didn't fix the problem. So I've opened msconfig, chosen "Selective Startup" and Windows started good without any problem, so I think it's something linked with Microsoft Services.

I've also seen msconfig services after a normal boot (with all Microsoft services active) and some Microsoft services result as "stopped". Can anyone help me?

[image: Bug]

Comment: Update BIOS, Chipset (if the computer has Chipset) and Video Drivers and restart, test.

Comment: I have fixed it formatting the SSD, creating a new partition and reinstalled windows for the second time.